# composer install --prefer-source throwing error

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

When I run `composer install --prefer-source` or try to update this one particular bundle ( others work well ) I get this error:

```
Failed to download some-bundle from source: Failed to execute git checkout 'xx' -- && git reset --hard 'xx' --

error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
...
    [ list of all files in repo on a branch that interests me ]
...
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I'm assuming I messed up something on the bundle repository, but have no idea what.

1. I clone brand new project repository
2. I try "composer install --prefer source" and still get that error.

What is interesting - the error occurs only on docker on MAC. On other pc with linux it works fine.

Comment: What version of composer? Someone else reported the same issue, and an update to composer sorted them out. Worth a try? "For other people running into this problem try composer update --prefer-dist". Other suggestions are run in GIT Bash and not CMD (windows).

Comment: Composer version 1.2.1 2016-09-12 11:27:19. --prefer-dist doesn't work as I want - I can't send changes directly from vendor. But I think it's the issue only on MAC.

Comment: The solution is to never, *ever* make modifications inside of the vendor folder. That is directly opposed to the entire point of composer, the vendor folder, and proper development practices in general.

Comment: @Sammitch this is actually not true, f.e. if you want to develop a package with application context it's a valid option to get the trunk/branch and develop it directly in the vendor directory. For this reason composer will warn you about changes before install/update.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you have manually updated the sources in your vendor directory of this bundle.

If so, try to commit/push or reset them directly in the vendor directory before updating the package.

If not, it may relates to this issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2896

The author writes:

"This can be fixed in two ways:

- when stashing, add --include-untracked flag which will stash newly added files as well.
- when checking out, add --force flag which will overwrite files instead of aborting."

If nothing helps you can manually delete the vendor directory to force composer to newly install the package.
**Edit** Please take also a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#clear-cache, maybe composer has cached the git repository somewhere and cannot update it.

Comment: I've edited my question. The error is still there even if I start from scratch.

Comment: @mmmm maybe composer has cached something internally, I have edited my response

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache, and still even when I start from cloning new repo and install vendors on docker I get an error.

Comment: @mmmm In this case I don't think I can help you any futher without knowing the environment. What I can suggest you is to execute the composer command in verbose mode `--verbose (-v)` and put the result in your question with as much information as possible. It seems like something is either broken in git repo or it's a general bug in composer.

Comment: I thinks it's somehow related to docker on MAC, because as I said - on other PC, with linux, everything works fine. `--verbose` haven't said anything more about that.

Comment: maybe docker uses a global composer cache or vendor directory where it couldn't modify the files because there are changes from another docker instance, but that is just a guess